# ORA-00947:not enough values

Tags: oracle, plsql

guys i am getting error that PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values while running my code.

```
declare
    type e_type is record ( last_name employees.last_name%type,
                             email employees.email%type,
                             hire_date employees.hire_date%type,
                             job_id employees.job_id%type);
      type e_list is table of e_type index by pls_integer;
      emps e_list;
    begin
      for x in 100 .. 110 loop
        select last_name,email,hire_date,job_id into emps(x) from employees 
           where employee_id = x ;
           ---dbms_output.put_line(emps(x).email);
           insert into emp(last_name,email,hire_date,job_id) values emps(x);
      end loop;
    end;
```

Comment: Does it not say in which line the problem is?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PL%2FSQL+ORA-00947 for one, but in any case you should include a [mcve] in your question. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: please edit the question and show the table definition

Comment: my table -EMPLOYEE_ID             NUMBER(6)  ,  
FIRST_NAME              VARCHAR2(20) ,
LAST_NAME      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25) ,
EMAIL          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25) ,
PHONE_NUMBER            VARCHAR2(20), 
HIRE_DATE      NOT NULL DATE         ,
JOB_ID         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10), 
SALARY                  NUMBER(8,2)  ,
COMMISSION_PCT          NUMBER(2,2),  
MANAGER_ID              NUMBER(6)    ,
DEPARTMENT_ID           NUMBER(4),

Comment: its line 13 where i am trying to insert selected no of columns from one table to another. when i select all columns and try to insert them from one table to another .it allows me to do that but when i go with selected columns then it gives me error. both table structure is same because i created table by using as keyword and copy the same table by taking its new name

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
insert into emp(last_name,email,hire_date,job_id)
values emp(x);
```

The PL/SQL [INSERT Statement Extension](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/INSERT-statement-extension.html) where you use a record variable for the `values` clause does not accept a column list, so it needs to be either

```
insert into emp values emp(x);
```

where `emp(x)` evaluates to a record matching the entire `emp` row, or else

```
insert into
( select last_name, email, hire_date, job_id from emp )
values emp(x);
```

where `emp(x)` is a record exactly matching the `select` list.

Answer (score 0):

@WilliamRobertson presents an interesting solution (I had actually forgotten that format). However there is still a much simpler solution. That is to use a single sql statement for the select and insert while avoiding the type and variable declarations and the loop altogether:

```
insert into emp(last_name,email,hire_date,job_id) 
  select last_name,email,hire_date,job_id
    from employees  
   where employee_id between 100 and 110;
```

Comment: i know this query bro ,i am just trying to do the same by using coding skills ,i just want to know where is the problem even i am taking same column in same order as my record but even then it does not allow to insert when i select whole table then it allows to insert and your this query (insert into emp values emp(x) is giving same error .